# Selecting the second result of a "Find" with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to make it so that I can find the second result for "lights", in case of having various occurrences for this term. The code below finds the first occurrence in the range under consideration.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim y As Range

     Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 3)
    Range(x.Address(0, 0)).Select
    Selection.Find(What:="Lights", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

      Selection.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
      Selection.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Select
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. Could you please explain what you are intending to do? Firstly you search for "1" and then (in the range where "1" was found) for "Lights". Say in plain words what you want to do exactly.

Comment: The code  finds "1" in the column b, then moves the activecell to column e on the row which contained 1 in b, then selects a the range down to the end of the occupied cells ... the last part of it starting with Lights Find is the key part. I want it to find the nth (i.e., second or third

Comment: Your question was clear. I asked that to make sure that the code above was doing what you wanted. Will write my answer right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindNext` delivers what you want. Using it is easy: perform the first search as you are doing it right now (although by assigning the result to a `Range`) and take the resulting range as starting point for `FindNext`. Here you have a sample code adapted to your specific requirements (`secondAddress` is the `Address` of the second occurrence of "Light", if any):

```
   Dim foundRange As Range
   Dim rangeToSearch As Range
   Set rangeToSearch = Selection
   Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.Find(What:="Lights", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False) 'First Occurrence

     Dim secondAddress As String
    If (Not foundRange Is Nothing) Then
        foundRange.Activate
        Dim count As Integer: count = 0
        Dim targetOccurrence As Integer: targetOccurrence = 2
        Dim found As Boolean

        Do While Not found
            Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.FindNext(foundRange)
            If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
                count = count + 1
                If (count >= targetOccurrence - 1) Then
                    secondAddress = foundRange.Address
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
               Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
  End If
```

Comment: Works great, should be foundrange.Next (currently foundrangeNext).

Comment: @RichardPullman actually just foundRange. It was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I found an even easier way as it sounds like I had a similar problem.

If you simplified your search function:

```
Cells.Find(What:="xxxx", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

Then add another line beneath:

```
Cells.Find(What:="xxxx", After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

All this does is find the first occurrence of "xxxx", then the second code finds "xxxx", but begins searching from the result of the first find code (which was the ActiveCell).